# Adjugate of rank $n-1$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

I'm working on this problem:

Given $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix with $\operatorname{rank} A = n-1$, how to find its adjugate matrix?

I have solved the case when (algebraic) multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ is $1$.

### Definition

The **adjugate** of a matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{n\times n}$, denoted $\operatorname{adj} A$, is $(M_{ji})_{n\times n}$, where $M_{ij}$ is the determinant of the submatrix of $A$ with row $j$ and column $i$ removed, multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$.

The **conjugate transpose** of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is denoted $A^*$.

### Pre conditions

Assume a Jordan form decomposition of $A$ is given:
$$
A = MJM^{-1},
$$
which means all eigenvalues of $A$, plus their multiplities, the Jordan blocks, and the corresponding Jordan basis are known.

It would be welcomed if you need to add new conditions to answer this question.

### My Solution

As $\operatorname{rank} A = n-1$, there exists $p\neq 0$ such that $Ap=0$, and if $Ax=0$ then $x=kp$ for some $k\in \mathbb{C}$.
For $A^*$, there also exists $q\neq 0$ such that $A^*q=0$, and if $A^*y=0$ then $y= k'q$ for some $k'\in \mathbb{C}$.

Note that $\operatorname{rank} \operatorname{adj} A = 1$, so there exists nonzero $x, y\in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\operatorname{adj} A = xy^*$.

As $(\operatorname{adj} A)A = A(\operatorname{adj} A) = (\det A)I = 0$, we have
$$
    x(A^*y)^* = (Ax)y^* = 0.
    $$

Then $x,y\neq 0$ implies $A^*y = Ax=0$, which means there exists a scalar $k\in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
    \operatorname{adj} A = k(pq^*).
    $$

Set all eigenvalues of $A$ be $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$, where $\lambda_1=0$, which are repeated by their multiplicities. A Jordan form of $A$ is
$$
    J = \begin{pmatrix}
        J_1 & &\\
        & \ddots &\\
        & & J_m
    \end{pmatrix}
    $$
where $J_1 = (0)$ and $J_k$ is the Jordan block with the same nonzero entries
on its diagonal and $1$'s on its upper subdiagonal.

If
$$
    J = \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 1 & &\\
         & \ddots & \ddots & \\
         & & \ddots & 1\\
         & & & \lambda
    \end{pmatrix}
    $$
is a Jordan block with $\lambda\neq 0$, then its inverse is $J^{-1} = (k_{ij})$, where
\begin{equation}
    k_{ij} = \begin{cases}
        0,&\quad\text{if $i>j$},\\
        \lambda^{-1},&\quad\text{if $i=j$},\\
        (-1)^{i+j}\lambda^{i-j+1},&\quad\text{if $i<j$}.
    \end{cases}\tag{1}
    \end{equation}

For matrix $A$, there exists a matrix $M$ whose first column is $p$, such that
$$
    A = MJM^{-1}.
    $$

By the continuity of matrices, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\det(A+\epsilon I)\neq 0 \quad \text{for all $\epsilon \in (0,\delta)$}.
$$
Then
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
        \operatorname{adj}(A+\epsilon I) &= \det(A+\epsilon)(A+\epsilon I)^{-1}\\
        &= \prod_{i=1}^n{(\lambda_i+\epsilon)}(M(J+\epsilon I)^{-1}M^{-1})\\
        &= M\begin{pmatrix}
            \prod_{i=2}^n(\lambda_i+\epsilon) & & & \\
                & \prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i+\epsilon)(J_2+\epsilon I)^{-1} & &\\
                & &\ddots & \\
                & & & \prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i+\epsilon)(J_k+\epsilon I)^{-1}
        \end{pmatrix}M^{-1}.
    \end{split}\tag{2}\end{equation}

By the structure of $J_k^{-1}$ with $k\geq 2$, when $\epsilon \to 0$, $\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i+\epsilon)(J_k+\epsilon I)^{-1}\to 0$.
This means
\begin{equation}
    \operatorname{adj}(A) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\operatorname{adj} (A+\epsilon I) = M\begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda^* & & &\\
         & 0 & &\\
         & &\ddots &\\
         & & & 0
    \end{pmatrix}M^{-1},\tag{3}
    \end{equation}

where $\lambda^* = \prod_{i=2}^n \lambda_i$.

For $\operatorname{adj} A = kpq^*$, the nonzero eigenvalue of $\operatorname{adj} A$ is $k(q^*p)$. From $(1)$, the nonzero eigenvalue of $\operatorname{adj} A$ is $\lambda^*$, so
$$
k = (q^*p)^{-1}\prod_{i=2}^n\lambda_i,
$$
and
$$
 \operatorname{adj} A = \prod_{i=2}^n \lambda_i \frac{pq^*}{q^*p}.\tag(4)
$$

### Problem remained

When the mutiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ is not $1$, $J_1\neq (0)$, and $\prod_{i=1}^n(\lambda_i+\epsilon)(J_1+\epsilon I)^{-1}$ diverges when $\epsilon \to 0$, so the method above seem to fail.

At the same time, I'm also not sure whether equation $(3)$ works. Are there any algebraic method solving this problem?

### Processes (updating)

1. Equation (4) seems to be true for arbitrary matrices by numerical checking; sometimes $(-1)$ should be multiplied. I think that it depends on whether $d$, the multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$, is even or odd. (It seems to be $(-1)^{d+1}$.)
2. If $A = MJM^{-1}$ with multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ be $d$, then $\operatorname{adj}(A) = kME_{1d}M^{-1}$, where $E_{1d}$ is an $n\times n$ matrices with $(1,d)$ entry be $1$, and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: I assume you mean adjoint in the classical sense, i.e. the [adjugate/adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) matrix? I'm not sure what the problem is; can't you just compute the cofactors of nullity $1$ matrices, just like any other square matrix?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, this "adjoint" means adjugate matrix. The problem would be easy if cofactors were computable, but it would be hard for an abstract matrix.

Comment: @TheoBendit I need to add some pre conditions in my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't examined the details of your approach, but it seems overly complicated. Here's another approach. First note that $\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)$ is characterized by the identity
$$\det(Ax_1,\ldots,Ax_{n-1},x_n)=\det(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)x_n)\tag{1}$$
If $\mathop{\mathrm{rank}}A=n-1$, then $\mathop{\mathrm{im}}\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)=\ker(A)$. Indeed, on the one hand
$$A\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)x=\det(A)x=0x=0$$
so $\mathop{\mathrm{im}}\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)\subseteq\ker(A)$. On the other hand we can choose a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ with $\langle v_n\rangle=\ker(A)$ and choose $v$ so that $Av_1,\ldots,Av_{n-1},v$ is a basis. Plugging these values into (1) shows that $\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)v\ne0$ so $0\ne\mathop{\mathrm{im}}\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)=\ker(A)$.

It follows that $\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)=f\otimes v_n$ where $f$ is a linear functional. If we scale so that $\det(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=1$, then by (1)
$$f(x)=\det(Av_1,\ldots,Av_{n-1},x)\tag{2}$$
You can plug the basis vectors in (2) to compute an explicit matrix representation for $\mathop{\mathrm{adj}}(A)$.

Comment: Good answer. I would accept it as my gratitude.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ is $d$. We first discuss the condition when $A$ is a Jordan form.

As geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $0$ is $1$, the super-diagonal entries of $0$-Jordan block are all $1$. For example,
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is valid, but
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is not.

In general, if all distinct eigenvalues of $J$ are $\lambda_1=0,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_m$, with multiplicities $d_1=d,d_2,\dots,d_m$, then $J$ is of the form
$$
J = \begin{pmatrix}
J_1 & & & \\
 & J_2 & &\\
 & &\ddots& \\
 & & &J_m
\end{pmatrix},\tag{1}
$$
where $J_i$ is the Jordan block belonging to eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, and
$$
J_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 &        &\\
  & 0 & \ddots &\\
  &   & \ddots & 1\\
  &   &        & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

By simple calculation, an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $0$ of $J$ is $e_1$, the first vector of natural basis. For $J^*$, it is $e_d$.

This means there exists a scalar $k\in \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
\operatorname{adj}(J) = ke_1e_d^* := kE_{1d}.
$$

By definition, $k$ is the cofactor of $J(d,1)$. It is
$$
(-1)^{d+1}\begin{vmatrix}
1&      & &   &      &\\
 &\ddots& &   &      &\\
 &      &1&   &      &\\
 &      & &J_2&      &\\
 &      & &   &\ddots&\\
 &      & &   &      &J_m
\end{vmatrix} = (-1)^{d+1}\prod_{i=2}^m{\lambda_i^{d_i}},
$$
which means
$$
\operatorname{adj}(J) = \left((-1)^{d+1}\prod_{i=2}^m{\lambda_i^{d_i}}\right)E_{1d},
$$
where $E_{1d}$ is the $n\times n$ matrix with $0$'s on its entries except for $(1,d)$ entry, which is $1$.

For arbitrary matrix $A$, let $A = MJM^{-1}$ be its Jordan decomposition.
Then, by identity $\operatorname{adj}(AB) = \operatorname{adj}(B)\operatorname{adj}(A)$, we have
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\operatorname{adj}(A) &= \operatorname{adj}(MJM^{-1})\\
&= \operatorname{adj}(M^{-1})\operatorname{adj}(J)\operatorname{adj}(M)\\
&= \det(M^{-1})(M^{-1})^{-1}\operatorname{adj}(J)\det(M)M^{-1}\\
&= \left((-1)^{d+1}\prod_{i=2}^m\lambda_i^{d_i}\right)ME_{1d}M^{-1}.
\end{split}\end{equation*}

By the discussions above, if $p$, $q$ are eigenvectors belonging to eigenvalue $0$ of $A$, $A^*$, respectively, then we can choose
$$
p = Me_1,\quad q = (M^*)^{-1}e_d,
$$
and
$$
pq^* = ME_{1d}M^{-1}.
$$

This means
$$
\operatorname{adj}(A) = \left((-1)^{d+1}\prod_{i=2}^m\lambda_i^{d_i}\right)pq^*.
$$

### Proposition

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix with $\operatorname{rank} A = n-1$. If all distinct eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1=0,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_m$, with multiplicities $d_1=d,d_2,\dots,d_m$, and $Ap=A^*q=0$ for $p,q\neq 0$, then
$$
\operatorname{adj}(A) = \left((-1)^{d+1}\prod_{i=2}^m\lambda_i^{d_i}\right)\frac{pq^*}{q^*p}.
$$